# Как с помощью canvas растянуть изображение на весь экран, без потери качества

Tags: canvas, flash, изображения, html5

Помогите решить проблему. Нужно с помощью canvas растянуть изображение на весь экран, без потери качества. И чтоб при изменении размеров окна изображение подстраивалось под размеры. Вообщем заказчик хочет как тут (http://www.a-gu.ru/). На этом сайте реализовано с помощью флеша.

Или подскажите другие способы решения проблемы. Буду благодарен за ссылки на флеш-модули, которые так растягивают изображение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что лучше canvas, flash или css3 вам выбирать, да.

Вот с канвой [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/LSn24/). Только надо еще правильно ширину и высоту считать и смещение, когда размеры окна имеют отличные от картинки пропорции. В общем все возможно и реализуемо.

Comment: Я уверен, есть уже какой-нибудь плагин, который это просчитывает

Comment: плагин для двух строк кода? [вот](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/LSn24/) и весь расчет.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите на эти примеры: [непринужденные фоновые изображения на весь экран с помощью jQuery](http://www.coolwebmasters.com/tutorials/1116-effortless-full-screen-background-images-with-jquery.html).